# Count double palindromes in given int sequence

Tags: algorithm, palindrome

For a given int sequence check number of double palindromes, where by double palindrome we mean sequence of two same palindromes without break between them. So for example:

in 1 0 1 1 0 1 we have 1 0 1 as a palindrome which appears 2 times without a break,

in 1 0 1 5 1 0 1 we have 1 0 1 but it's separated

(apart from the other palindromes in these sequences)

Problem example test data is:

> 3
>
> 12 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 0
>
> 12 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0
>
> 6 3 3 3 3 3 3

with answers

> 8 0 9

Manacher is obvious for the begging, but I'm not sure what to do next. Any ideas appreciated. Complexity should be below n^2 I guess.

EDIT: int is here treated as single element of alphabet

Comment: Is this homework? It doesn't seem like a problem with practical relevance...

Comment: Are you looking for ALL palindromes or just the longest ones? Your examples contain the palindromes `11` and `00` as sub-palindromes of others. Should they *all* be recognized, or not? (I'm assuming that a requirement is `length(palindrome)>1`).

Comment: Yes, answer is a number of all palindromes, length of single part might be 1 as it seems from example test data.

@Mark - You could call it this way. It has no practical relevance... Its part of usual algorithms subject on university.

Comment: @jakubmal: Did your professor discuss algorithms for finding all palindromes? What if we restricted those palindromes to be even length?

Comment: @Moron: I meant Manacher to be the algorithm for finding all palindromes (and it was presented). I get rid of even/odd palindromes problem by inserting -1 between every element when reading from io. Actually I'm in High School, but we have a kind of AP program.

Comment: @jakubmal: Not sure what Manacher does, but aren't you just looking for even length palindromes? 'Double' palindrome, is just another palindrome with even number of elements...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you already know an algorithm for finding all palindromes (which BTW is pretty awesome), all you need to do is the following. Note that a "double palindrome" is also a palindrome:
reverse(PP) = reverse(P)reverse(P) = PP.

So among all palindromes `(a,b)` you find (where by `(a,b)` I mean a palindrome from position `a` to position `b`), you need to find `(i,j,k)` such that `(i,j)`, `(j,k)`, and `(i,k)` are all palindromes, and `j-i=k-j`. Equivalently, for each palindrome `(i,j)` you find, you just need to set `k = 2j-i`, and check whether both `(k,j)` and `(i,k)` are palindromes.

If the first step returns M palindromes in all, this takes O(M) time (assuming you stored them such that checking whether a palindrome exists is O(1)), so O(n<sup>2</sup>) in the worst case. I believe this should be optimal in the worst case (consider a string of all 1s).

Comment: Basically that's it. We can further decrease complexity by applying some clever algorithm for counting double-palindromes. It's quite similar to Manacher, since it only checks current greatest palindrome and automatically appends smaller ones to interval (??) tree.

Answer (score 0):

I would start with 2 collections:

- a collection of 'growing' sequences
- a collection of 'shrinking' sequences

The algorithm works like this:

- Initially both collections are empty
- Handle the values of the vector one by one, assume we are now looking at value V
- Loop over all 'growing' sequences

  - If the last value of a growing sequence is equal to V, copy the growing sequence to the collection of shrinking sequences, remove V from the end of the new shrinking sequence
  - If the one-but-last value of the growing sequence is equal to V, copy the growing sequence to the collection of shrinking sequences, remove the last 2 elements (V and the last one) from the shrinking sequence
- Loop over all 'shrinking' sequences

  - If the last value of the shrinking sequence is equal to V, remove it from the shrinking sequence.  If a shrinking sequence becomes empty, we have found a palindrome.
  - If the last value of the shrinking sequence is not equal to V, delete this shrinking sequence
- Finally make a new growing sequence consisting of only V

In fact the growing sequences are sequences that might become a palindrome once, while the shrinking sequences are 'partially' a palindrome.